# Is it possible to do a case conversion with regexp_replce in snowflake?

Tags: sql, regex, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do a case conversion in snowflake using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, however it seems that it doesn't support the appropriate escape sequence.

Example: I'd like to take `hello_world` and make it say `Hello_World`

I've tried:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('hello_world', '(^[a-z]|_[a-z])', '\\U\\1', 1, 0, 'c');
```

> Replace string could not be rewritten, pattern: `'(^[a-z]|_[a-z])'`, replace string: `'\U\1'`, reason: invalid escape sequence

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('hello_world', '(^[a-z]|_[a-z])', UPPER('\\1'), 1, 0, 'c')
```

Wrapping `UPPER` around the replacement did nothing as expected as well.

I'd really like to avoid some concatenation solution as the SQL will get ugly and difficult to maintain fast.

Another Example: I'd like to take `HelloWorld` and make it say `hello_world`

similar to above I get the same error:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('HelloWorld', '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1\\L\\2', 1, 0, 'c');
```

> Replace string could not be rewritten, pattern: `'([a-z])([A-Z])'`, replace string: `'\1\L\2'`, reason: invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 2):

No need for complicated regular expressions. Snowflake supports [string function `INITCAP()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/initcap.html), which does exactly what you want:

```
select initcap('hello world')
```

Comment: Thanks this may partially solve my issue, but I still need regex to support other use cases beyond the simple one I mentioned here.

Comment: can you ask a question with the more complicated case? maybe we can solve that one too

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I've added a 2nd example above.